# Python Print/Write String containing "\f"

Tags: python, string

I am trying to read a file and replace every "a ... a" by a '\footnotemark'

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as myfile:
   data = myfile.read()
   data = re.sub('<a.+?</a>', '\footnotemark', data)
```

Somehow Python always makes '\footnotemark' to '\x0cootnotemark' ('\f' to '\x0c'). I tried so far

- Escaping: '{2 Backslashes}footnotemark'
- raw String: r'\footnotemark' or r'"\footnotemark"'

None of these worked

Example input:

```
foo<a href="anything">asdasd</a> bar
```

Example output:

```
foo\footnotemark bar
```

Comment: `r'\\footnotemark'`

Comment: This gives me `\\footnotemark`

Comment: post an example along with expected output. BTW why are you trying to replace a html tag using regex?

Comment: above comment is correct. Python interpreter should show double \\ because of repr.

Comment: Why wouldn't you make it `foo<footnotemark> bar` (so implement '<>' instead of backslash)? This is closer to the content of the original file type (html) AND easier to process (`re.sub(u'<a.+?</a>', '<footnotemark>', data)`).

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra `\footnotemark` is a LATEX command and therefore it has to be this way.

Comment: Almost right. You actually want r'\footnotemark'. When you have the r in front of a string, every character in the string is escaped as if a \ was added before each character. That's why having r'\\' makes 2 \s appear.

Comment: @LeoCHan: No, that doesn't work properly.  Avinash Raj's original comment is correct: `r'\\footnotemark'` is the required string; alternatively: `'\\\\footnotemark'`. That's because 2 levels of escaping are required, one level for Python itself, one level for the regex syntax. FWIW, `\f` is a formfeed, i.e., a page-break control character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Python2 since You haven't mentioned anything about version

```
#/usr/bin/python

import re

# myfile is saved with utf-8 encoding
with open('myfile', 'r') as myfile:

    text = myfile.read()
    print text
    data = re.sub('<a.+?</a>', r'\\footnotemark', text)

print data
```

outputs

```
foo<a href="anything">asdasd</a> bar
foo\footnotemark bar
```